# Vue-js removed selected date from textbox when add new element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-datepicker, vuejs2

Vue-js remove selected date from textbox when add new element. if i entered any text instead of date and add new element text is display as is it. but date is removed.

below is my HTML code

```
<div class="dateAvailabilityContainer">

            <div class="dateAvailability" v-for="(date, index) in dates">
                <div class="form-group date">
                    <input type="text" v-model='date.date' class="form-control date" v-bind:class="'datepicker_'+index" placeholder="Date">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" v-model='date.from' class="form-control from" placeholder="From">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" v-model='date.to' class="form-control to" placeholder="To">
                </div>
                <a href="#" v-if="index == 0" class="btn btn-success" v-on:click="addNewDate">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="#" v-if="index > 0" class="btn btn-danger" v-on:click="removeThisDate(index)">
                    <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
```

and below is my vue-js code

```
var addAvailability = new Vue({
        el: '#addAvailability',
        data: {
            dates : [{
                date : '',
                from : '',
                to : '',
            }],
        },
        mounted: function () {
            this.addDatePicker( this.dates.length - 1 );
        },
        methods: {
            addNewDate: function () {
                this.dates.push({
                    date: '',
                    from: '',
                    to: '',
                });
                this.addDatePicker( this.dates.length - 1 );
            },
            removeThisDate : function(index){
                this.dates.splice(index, 1);
            },
            addDatePicker : function( id ){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    console.log('.datepicker_'+id);
                    $('.datepicker_'+id).datepicker({
                        autoclose: true,
                    });
                },500);
            }
        }
    });
```

please help where i create a mistake.

please check in fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/renishkhunt/bod4ob5y/19/

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide a fiddle reproducing the error?

Comment: @AldoRomo88 please check in Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/renishkhunt/bod4ob5y/19/

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap (js) and jquery aren't friendly working with vue.

I think that it is because they modify DOM directly while vue also has a virtual DOM and works in a more data driven way.

Make them work together requires extra logic, I could only fix `datetimepicker`, I never haven't work with `clockpicker` before

First I change `addNewDate` function

```
//Save new date in a variable
var dateModel = {
  date: '',
  from: '',
  to: '',
};
this.dates.push(dateModel);
var elementId = "datepicker_"+(this.dates.length - 1);
//pass new date to initDate function
this.initDate( elementId, dateModel );
```

In `initDate` we need to listen for date changes and update model

```
$('#'+id).datepicker({
   ...
}).on('changeDate', function(e){
    dateModel.date = e.format();
});
```

Please see this partially working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AldoRomo88/skt8hrz3/)

As alternative you could use [vue-flatpickr](https://jrainlau.github.io/vue-flatpickr/), at this moment is the best "vue's way" that I have found to handle date time inputs

Comment: AldoRomo88 is correct - you have to hook the change event for the calendar widget and make sure that it is applied to the model after the picker closes. You can see this pretty clearly if you use Vue DevTools in Chrome.